# Can anything be done with this partable disk? Not detected as hard drive anymore

Tags: usb, hard-drive

My portable disk apparently failed (stopped being detected as a disk suddenly, as script was writing data to it).

On restart it reappeared, what allowed me to review data and confirm that I have nothing actually important there (has backups/is backups/tmp files)

`dmesg` shows

```
[  527.769272] usb 2-3: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[  527.782033] usb 2-3: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa, bcdDevice= 1.00
[  527.782041] usb 2-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[  527.782047] usb 2-3: Product: USB 3.0 device
[  527.782052] usb 2-3: Manufacturer: Intenso
[  527.782058] usb 2-3: SerialNumber: 30200000000000001026
[  527.787474] scsi host3: uas
[  527.788340] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Intenso  USB 3.0 device   0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  527.789574] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Spinning up disk...
[  527.790112] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[  528.814988] ..................................................................................................not responding...
[  648.979675] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  648.979684] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  648.979689] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[  669.829324] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  669.829405] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
[  669.829428] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Add. Sense: Logical unit is in process of becoming ready
[  669.829894] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  669.829904] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] 0-byte physical blocks
```

`lsblk` does not list

Should I try anything else before hammering it (as paranoid person I prefer to ensure that data cannot be recovered) and putting it into e-waste container?

Comment: It could be the enclosure the drive is in has stopped working.  Happened several times to me with external drives.  The most I was able to do was to pull the drive out of the enclosure then use like TestDisk to recover the data and store it somewhere else.  Then I had to reformat the drive (most large external drives the enclosures do something special to the drive) so that it could be used as an internal drive.  If the drive is dead, smashing it or shredding it would be the best most secure way to protect your data.

Comment: @Terrance It seems to be good enough as answer (even better would be linking some hint/instructions/manual how to pull it out and connect without using possibly broken enclosure parts)